Не могу отправить сообщения в сторонний чат (tg bot)
У меня есть inline кнопка, которую я описываю в начале кода
elif query.data == 'notification_photomaker': 
    await query.edit_message_text("Пожалуйста, введите ваше замечание:") 
    return "AWAITING_NOTE"

также я задал состояние AWAITING_NOTE
AWAITING_NOTE = 1

я бы хотел, чтобы после нажатия на нее, пользователь вводил данные, которые сохранялись бы, поэтому я создал AWAITING_NOTE и описал его
AWAITING_NOTE: [MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, notification_photomaker_button)],

далее, соответственно, когда бот переходит в состояние AWAITING_NOTE - вызывается функция для сохранения записей, которые ввел пользователь
async def notification_photomaker_button(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> int: 
    notif_dict = update.message.text.strip() 
    context.chat_data.pop("chat_data", None) 
    context.chat_data[notif_dict] = notif_dict 
     
    chat_id = "-10024672"    
    await send_message_photomaker(chat_id, notif_dict, bot) 
    await update.message.reply_text("Сообщение отправлено фотомейкеру.", reply_markup=back_step()) 
    return ConversationHandler.END

ну и функция для отправки сообщения
async def send_message_photomaker(chat_id: str, text: str, context) -> None: 
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=text)

почему не работает так, как я хотел бы? в данный момент я получаю только сообщение в боте, "Пожалуйста, введите ваше замечание:" то есть срабатывает только 1ый шаг. Функция просто меня игнорирует
Полный код можно просмотреть тут: https://github.com/socialrave/inspection360.git

всем спасибо, все исправил
